# Ignore entity field while creation, Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create some default values for some field inside entity.

This is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="tokens", insertable = false)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    private List<String> tokens;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="permission", insertable = false, columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default 0")
    private Integer permission;

    @Column(name="deleted", columnDefinition = "boolean default false", insertable = false)
    private boolean deleted;

    @Column(name="expirationDate", insertable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date expirationDate;

}
```

The fields that I want to receive from the client is:
`email, password, firstName, lastName`.

This is my route that receive the input and persist it:

```
@PostMapping("/createUser")
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        try{
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .body(userService.addUser(user));
        } catch (CustomException e){
            throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Via the annotation `@RequestBody` I am able to send an json to the server:

```
    {
    "email": "itshakbarcd45v@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "firstName": "Itzik",
    "lastName": "Barabie",
    "permission": 4,
    "deleted": "true"
}
```

And it's seem to be that the user can specify it's own values for fields `permission` and `deleted`, Which I have annotate then with `insertable = false`.

This is the returned object.

```
{
    "userId": 6,
    "createDate": "2022-02-14T22:38:21.892+00:00",
    "updatedDate": "2022-02-14T22:38:21.892+00:00",
    "deleted": true,
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "85784496ddc1811f5b71ee2a2797924139c550f784bd72753bc4daa9e731e148a0e57067038b5d4a82e2cecf910505ad06ec49a12d777a81f471ef81f8bae9ef",
    "tokens": null,
    "firstName": "Itzik",
    "lastName": "Barabie",
    "permission": 4,
    "expirationDate": "2022-02-14T22:38:21.892+00:00"
}
```

This is an expected behavior? Or I'm missing something..
I have understand that `insertable = false` and `updateable = false` should block any attempt for insert or update manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the JPA insertable/updatable behavior, you should not expose Entities on API boundries, so you should have something like UserDTO (data transfer object) which is the actual object your clients interact with enabling you to hide implementation details (and not deal with this stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to restrict the API from accessing the fields that are only meant for internal use in the service layer such as permission/delete, then you are better off using

> @JsonIgnore

or

> @JsonProperty

annotations instead of @Insertable or @Updatable. This will hide the fields from the API.

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="tokens", insertable = false)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    private List<String> tokens;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="permission", columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default 0")
    private Integer permission;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="deleted", columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean deleted;

    @Column(name="expirationDate", insertable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date expirationDate;

}
```

You can also choose to make the fields optionally hide during either a read or write. For example

> @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)

will show the value in API but not allow it to be written.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to created an another custom controller that able to modify those variables, how's that can happen if I block the access to them?
I don't want to allow insertion of those fields inside the current route

Comment: In that case you should preferably write DTOs instead of directly using Spring Data REST. Your use case is clear, you want the same Entity to behave differently in different REST contexts. Then you must explicitly do the Entity to DTO mapping for them at least for one of the contexts. To make the Entity<->DTO conversion easier you can use Dozer

Comment: Thank you, I will try that, there is a chance you can give me some reference?

Comment: this is an excellent example, although it uses modelMapper instead of DozerMapper for implicit mapping. Observe the "convertToDTO" method. You can write two different implementations for it for two different contexts, first letting mapper do the implicit mapping, then overriding whatever values you want. https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Comment: I have created the DTO, and it fit perfectly with the requirement.
But what if I have another route that use 3 fields of 5 fields that inside the DTO, should I create for it another DTO?

for example: I have `/addUser` route which use the `UserDto(userid,email,password,firstname,lastname)`

and I have another route `/updateUser` which I want it to use `firstName,Lastname` fields from the DTO.

what is the best-practice to do so, in stand of set them to null.

Comment: @Itzik.B you do not need to create another DTO. You can just write multiple implementations of "convertToDTO" method that manipulate different fields differently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242051/discussion-between-itzik-b-and-monish-sen).